# Fixed Object Path On Scroll

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I'm looking to make a site where when it is loaded there's a top view of a tiny car in the middle of the screen. The car is on a path and when you scroll the car will then make turns around these curves. For right now all I really can do is give the car a fixed postion in the middle of the screen with CSS and then set the road image as the background. The path would have to be straight for right now, because I have no idea where or how to make it turn these paths. Where do I even start?

Comment: It'd probably be easiest to use jQuery -- I'd tag this question with that.

Comment: Could I just use Javascript? I've just started coding JS and I guess I really don't know the difference between JS and JQ yet. @Danny-Cooper

Comment: You don't *need* jQuery, but it would likely help. I think you should look into binding the `onscroll` event handler on the `window` object, and `return false` to stop it propagating (stop it actually scrolling window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some small demo to demonstrate you possible solution. It uses css gradient instead of 'path' and you will have to make a lot of changes to implement multiple predefined turnings, but it works well I think:

http://jsfiddle.net/4Rkjg/5/

HTML:

```
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="car"></div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.car {
    position: fixed;
    top: 48%;
    left: 45%;
    width: 10%;
    height: 30px;
    background: blue;
}

.bg {
    width: 5000px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #f6e6b4;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #f6e6b4 0%, #e01616 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#f6e6b4), color-stop(100%,#e01616));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #f6e6b4 0%,#e01616 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #f6e6b4 0%,#e01616 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #f6e6b4 0%,#e01616 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #f6e6b4 0%,#e01616 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f6e6b4', endColorstr='#e01616',GradientType=1 );
}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){

    var $car = $('.car');
    var $bg = $('.bg');
    var carPosition = $car.position();

    var maxOffset = $bg.width() - $(window).width();

    $(window).scroll(function(e){
        var offset = $('body').scrollLeft();

        if(offset < maxOffset/2)
            var degree = offset / 100;
        else
            var degree = (maxOffset-offset)/100;

        // change rotation
        $car.css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            'zoom': 1
        });

        // change vertical position
        $car.css({
            'top': carPosition.top + offset/100
        });     
    });
});
```